# Flutter: how to prevent accidentally dragging a Draggable that is a child of a SingleChildScrollView from moving the Draggable instead of scrolling?

Tags: flutter, draggable, singlechildscrollview

I have Draggable widgets inside a SingleChildScrollView and to prevent the Draggable from being dragged when users' intention is to scroll, I thought to change them into LongPressDraggable with a delay, code blow:

```
         LongPressDraggable(
            delay: Duration(milliseconds: 200),
            axis: Axis.vertical,
            data: block,
            feedback: Opacity(
              opacity: kScheduledBlockFeedbackOpacity,
              child: Material(
                elevation: 10.0,
                shadowColor: Colors.black,
                child: scheduleBlock(block, scheduledBlockFeedbackColor),
              ),
            ),
            child: GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                print('onTap triggered 1');
                // go to details
                ...
              },
              child: block.action == 'pulling'
                  ? Opacity(opacity: kScheduledBlockFeedbackOpacity, child: scheduleBlock(block, scheduledBlockColor))
                  : scheduleBlock(block, scheduledBlockColor),
            ),

            childWhenDragging: Container(),
            onDragStarted: () {
              ...
            },
            onDragUpdate: (DragUpdateDetails d) {
              ...
            },
            onDragEnd: (DraggableDetails d) {
              ...
            })
```

The problem is whenever the LongPressDraggable's delay property is present, its child GestureDetector's onTap doesn't trigger.  Even if the delay is set to 0, making it work with same as a Draggable.

How can I get around this problem?  Or is there a better way to prevent dragging on a Draggable within a SingleChildScrollView from moving the Draggable instead of scrolling?

Update 5/31/23

```
                        Positioned(
                          child: LongPressDraggable(
                            axis: Axis.vertical,
                            // feedbackOffset: Offset(0, offSet),
                            onDragStarted: () {},
                            onDragUpdate: (DragUpdateDetails d) {},
                            onDragEnd: (DraggableDetails d) {},
                            childWhenDragging: Container(height: block.duration),
                            data: block,
                            child: Column(
                              children: [
                                // block.moved
                                selectedID == block.id
                                    ? LongPressDraggable()
                                    : DragTarget(builder: (context, candidateItems, rejectedItems) {}, 
                                    onMove: (DragTargetDetails d) {
                                        setState(() {});
                                      }),
                              ],
                            ),
                            // childWhenDragging: Container(),
                            feedback: Opacity(
                              opacity: opacity,
                              child: Material(
                                elevation: elevation,
                                shadowColor: Colors.black,
                                child: child,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        )
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm running into the exact same thing.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, @CliftonLabrum.  I updated my post with what ended up working for me.  It was a while a go so I hope this helps - by necessity I had to make the child of the LongPressDraggable either a DragTarget or a LongPressDraggable, and then noticed that this happily fixed the issue I had posted here.

Comment: That's exactly the solution I ended up finding.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly, you want to disable the scrolling property of the child inside `SingleChildScrollView()`?

Try setting `physics` to `NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()` in your child scrollable widget.

Comment: I want to prevent accidental dragging of a child inside SingleChildScrollView when user actually wants to scroll the scroll view